# turtlebot3_teleop turtlebot3_teleop_key.launch doesn't move

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am following the turtlebot3 tutorial.

In remote-PC, run

**roscore**

In turtlebot terminal, run

**roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_robot.launch**

then, back to remote-PC, run

**export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=buerger**

**rosrun rviz rviz -d rospack find turtlebot3_description /rviz/model.rviz**

can see the rviz GUI and the scan points.

then run,

**rqt**

can see the topics like odom, scan, battery, cm_vel_rc100, imu .......
then run,

**roslaunch turtlstrong textebot3_teleop turtlebot3_teleop_key.launch**

no error, see the wasd instructions. typing w, can see the acc refreshing with new speed.

**currently:    linear vel 0.09  angular vel 0.0**

**currently:    linear vel 0.01  angular vel 0.0**

but the robot doesn't move.
In topic "cmd_vel" is updated with new speed,
but in topic "cmd_vel_rc100 " the speed is still 0.

thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342747/turtlebot3_teleop-turtlebot3_teleop_key.launch-doesn%27t-move/) by [sinsinsinsin](https://answers.ros.org/users/51291/sinsinsinsin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2020-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

if you type `rostopic info cmd_vel` in the terminal, do you see anything subscribed to it? same for `rostopic info cmd_vel_rc100` is anything publishing to it?

---

Originally posted by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) with karma: 1124 on 2020-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sinsinsinsin](https://answers.ros.org/users/51291/sinsinsinsin/) on 2020-01-30**:
Thank you, Joe.
I run the demo again, it worked.
Check the topic ***cmd_vel*** and ***cmd_vel_rc100***.
the ***keyborad_tele*** node is publisher, and the ***ros_core*** is subscriber under the topic ***cmd_vel***.
in the topic ***cmd_vel_rc100*** only one publisher --- ***ros_core***, no subscriber.

the topic of ***cmd_vel*** can be found with ***rqt_graph*** command.

Thank you again, I will check with these commands next time.

**Comment by [rzeeshan565](https://answers.ros.org/users/100661/rzeeshan565/) on 2022-03-28**:
hi, I checked the cmd_vel and its showing correct values but robot doesn't move. All the hardware is setup properly.